# How many iops do I actually get in a General Purpose SQL Database in Azure?

Tags: azure, sql

I'm running a serverless SQL database in azure, taking a load from some data transformed by Databricks.

Every time I try to write to the database the, IOPS percentage shows up as 100% which makes it clear that this is my bottleneck.

In the database configuration tab, I can see that for general purpose I get 500-20000 IOPS provisioned. But how do I actually get and can I control this in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases#general-purpose---serverless-compute---gen5)

But in serverless mode you will have to look at limits for the vCores your DB is using at that second, so if vCores are 4 then you will have limit of 1280 and Throughput of '5-7 ms (write) and 5-10 ms (read)'

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a relevant except from the article in the answer directly?